# Html-верстка. Как выровнять блоки по центру?

Tags: html, float, display

Всем привет! Ситуация такая: не могу разобраться с блочной версткой. Допустим, имеются 4 блока. К каждому применен класс. И если каждому присвоить float:left; - они действительно выстраиваются в ряд, но не по центру. И можно более-менее отцентровать вручную с помощью margin. Но, в ручную, мне кажется, это делать неправильно. И когда я изменяю масштаб сайта - заметно видно, как эти блоки остаются в левой стороне, что некрасиво.
Делал с помощью второго варианта: присваиваю каждому display: inline-block. Но результат такой же. Хотя Вот видно (на скриншоте) выше, блок из 3х значков. Там используется display: inline-block. И они отлично находятся по центру при разном масштабе. 
В общем, как поступать? Что использовать?
[image: Уменьшенный масштаб]
[image: Блоки при float-left и 100% масштаб]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

помести все элементы в один див с классом например `<div class="content">` и в `CSS` напиши:

```
.content
{
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В случае с инлайн блоками нужно задавать родительскому элементу `text-align: center;`, а самим блокам `vertical-align: top;`.